# Refinerycms error when trying to access the dashboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

I'm trying to access the dashboard in my refinerycms app and I'm getting the following error:

```
 NoMethodError in Refinery/admin/dashboard#index

Showing /var/www/vhosts/tomstestsite.us/PersonalTrainingKT/app/views/refinery/admin/dashboard/_recent_activity.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined method `edit_group_fitness_classes_admin_group_fitness_clas_path' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy:0x0000000f11bfc0>

Extracted source (around line #4):

1: <div id='recent_activity'>
2:   <h2><%= t('.latest_activity') %></h2>
3:   <% if (activity = @recent_activity.collect { |a|
4:           activity_message_for(a)
5:         }.reject(&:blank?)).present? %>
6:     <ul class='clickable'>
7:     <% activity.each do |message| %>

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/refinery/admin/dashboard/_records.html.erb, app/views/refinery/admin/dashboard/index.html.erb

Rails.root: /var/www/vhosts/tomstestsite.us/PersonalTrainingKT
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/views/refinery/admin/dashboard/_recent_activity.html.erb:4:in `block in _app_views_refinery_admin_dashboard__recent_activity_html_erb__1848110473525801039_122287880'
app/views/refinery/admin/dashboard/_recent_activity.html.erb:3:in `collect'
app/views/refinery/admin/dashboard/_recent_activity.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_refinery_admin_dashboard__recent_activity_html_erb__1848110473525801039_122287880'
app/views/refinery/admin/dashboard/_records.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_refinery_admin_dashboard__records_html_erb__4550726393400955740_116529040'
app/views/refinery/admin/dashboard/index.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_refinery_admin_dashboard_index_html_erb__2977375506195649235_124556040'
```

group fitness classes is an engine I created.

Apparently if I try to add/edit/delete a group fitness class I get errors too.

Here's the error I get when trying to delete a group fitness class:

```
NoMethodError in Refinery::GroupFitnessClasses::Admin::GroupFitnessClassesController#destroy

undefined method `name' for #<Refinery::GroupFitnessClasses::GroupFitnessClass:0x0000000c8e6ed8>

Rails.root: /var/www/vhosts/tomstestsite.us/PersonalTrainingKT
```

**UPDATE**

I Changed my group_fitness_classes_controller from

```
module Refinery
  module GroupFitnessClasses
    module Admin
      class GroupFitnessClassesController < ::Refinery::AdminController

        crudify :'refinery/group_fitness_classes/group_fitness_class', :title_attribute => 'name', :xhr_paging => true

      end
    end
  end
end
```

to

```
module Refinery
  module GroupFitnessClasses
    module Admin
      class GroupFitnessClassesController < ::Refinery::AdminController

        crudify :'refinery/group_fitness_classes/group_fitness_class', :title_attribute => 'title', :xhr_paging => true

      end
    end
  end
```

end fixed the adding and deleting issues. Now it's the editing issue still.

Comment: Can you show use the result of `rake routes`. Do you have a name in your GroupFitnessClass? It's difficult to answer without the source code. Can you give the sources?

Comment: What source would you like to see?

Comment: What does `Refinery::GroupFitnessClasses::GroupFitnessClass.first.name` give you? Maybe a missing migration somewhere?

Comment: I don't have "name" in GroupFitnessClass. I have title. I may have had name at one time.

Comment: Sorry - here's the result: http://pastebin.com/wEDRXQR0

Comment: Please let me know what you'd like me to post for code.

Comment: If i comment out this line: `activity_message_for(a)` I don't get an error.

Comment: I just tried creating a new engine on my server and I get the same errors. Could it be a permissions issue or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was [a bug in Refinery that I've just fixed](https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms/commit/b5d5183ceba0beab3b7407ef70df9f95a7b71362) and will release version 2.0.6 for. Before that is out you can fix the problem in your application by placing this in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'refinerycms', :git => 'git://github.com/resolve/refinerycms.git', :branch => '2-0-stable'
```

This will use the git version until the gem is released (though this will happen today).

Thanks for your help in tracking down and fixing this bug over chat!

Phil

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a typo somewhere. Look at your first error:

```
undefined method `edit_group_fitness_classes_admin_group_fitness_clas_path'
```

should be

```
edit_group_fitness_classes_admin_group_fitness_class_path
```

Comment: I noticed that too, but i don't know where to edit that. That path is generated.

Comment: I'm new to rails and not really sure how to debug through `(activity = @recent_activity.collect { |a|`